# Using the field calculator in SAGA-GIS

Tags: field-calculator, saga, table, calculate-values

I am working with SAGA-GIS and need to create an euclidean allocation raster. For this, I need to first create an integer raster with values for certain areas. This integer raster shall be based on a vector for which a table exists. However, in this table, the value field contains only ones (=1). Now, I want to fill the value column with values from 1 to number of rows, in my case 98.

After reading the [description of the field calculator tool](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/5.0.0/table_calculus_2.html), I could not imagine how to do that as there is no sequence command or any way to access the previous or next row value.

It would be helpful if one could copy the rownames but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for five minutes more, I found the function "[enumerate table field](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/5.0.0/table_tools_2.html)" which does exactly this if you leave the attribute as "not set".

It was hidden under Table - Tools; maybe it should be moved into the Table -
 Calculus menu.

Comment: It is now called "Table Field Enumeration (Shapes)"